# does large value for -Xmx postpone Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection, heap-size

I have a lot of JVMs running on a Linux Redhat with 32GB of physical memory and a 32GB of virtual memory. these JVMs are configured to have a total value for Xmx which is more than 32GB and might have the Linux used its virtual memory.
my question is that if I specify the Xmx more than required heap size would it delay the Garbage Collection and as a result allocate more heapsize than necessary? so that it will cause the OS to allocate memory from its virtual memory which leads to a dwindled performance.

Comment: With virtual memory you probably meant swap, right? Virtual memory is something else.

Comment: it should postpone the `GC`, since it usually comes into play when certain parts of the `heap` are full. However, as it is documented, you can never be sure that the `GC` will ever start and when will it happen

Comment: Note that depending on your choice of JVM and GC, "garbage collection" might not be one large task, but instead happen incrementally all the time.

Comment: so GC is not aware of the memory type which might be physical or swap and since it hasn't met the xmx limitation, won't be forced to execute and keep using physical memory. right? I mean too loose and extra xmx will actually make the OS to use swap memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM reserves the maximum heap size (as well as other memory areas) on startup.  This means if you have a maximum heap size of 32 GB it will use about 33-35 GB of virtual memory including shared libraries threads etc.

Its is worth nothing that if you make the maximum heap size 32 GB it has to use 64-bit references and you can end up with less usable memory than a JVM with a maximum heap of 24 GB and it will use 32-bit references. Some people have estimated that if you make the heap size 32 Gb or more you have to increase it to 48 GB to get more usable memory.

Given the size of your machine I suggest you limit the heap to 24 GB (or less) and where possible use off heap memory as this can have both performance advantages and greater scalability.

If you have a low GC program and you want to avoid collection you can create a massive eden size and GC once per day or once per week.  To do this you have to keep your garbage discarded to a minimum and you could create an eden size of say 20 GB in which case provided you create less than 20 Gb in a day you can avoid triggering any GCs (even minor ones) and run a full GC as an over night maintainence task. e.g. at 2 am in the morning.

If you use a large heap, you want to avoid using the swap at all costs.  This is because the GC needs random access to the heap and as soon as one triggers which is large enough to swap, your machine will thrash for quite a long time (possibly hours), and possibly lock up.  You might even have to reboot to get you machine to behave normally. (it is hard to kill a process/machine which is in such a state)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name http://www.pubwithnoname.co.uk/ is also know as the white horse. ;)

Comment: actually in my case, the thrashing has happened and I'm trying to fix this by decreasing -xmx parameter to fit into 30GB hoping it won't be swapped, so otherwise you recommend to limit it to 24GB to make sure. Thank you Peter Lawrey

Comment: Don't forget you need space for the OS, and Java needs space for threads, permgen, shared libraries and direct memory it uses. Even switching from 32 to 30 GB can reduce the amount of memory used as it can use 32-bit references.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me to understand why my program runs out of heap space with -Xmx32g but not with -Xmx24g. I hadn't thought about the JVM needing to use 64 bit addresses!