# Java Heap Hard Drive

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have been working on a Java program that generates fractal orbits for quite some time now. Much like photographs, the larger the image, the better it will be when scaled down. The program uses a 2D object (Point) array, which is written to when a point's value is calculated. That is to say the Point is stored in it's corresponding value, I.e.:

```
Point p = new Point(25,30);
histogram[25][30] = p;
```

Of course, this is edited for simplicity. I could just write the point values to a CSV, and apply them to the raster later, but using similar methods has yielded undesirable results. I tried for quite some time because I enjoyed being able to make larger images with the space freed by not having this array. It just won't work. For clarity I'd like to add that the Point object also stores color data.

The next problem is the WriteableRaster, which will have the same dimensions as the array. Combined the two take up a great deal of memory. I have come to accept this, after trying to change the way it is done several times, each with lower quality results.

After trying to optimize for memory and time, I've come to the conclusion that I'm really limited by RAM. This is what I would like to change. I am aware of the -Xmx switch (set to 10GB). Is there any way to use Windows' virtual memory to store the raster and/or the array? I am well aware of the significant performance hit this will cause, but in lieu of lowering quality, there really doesn't seem to be much choice.

Comment: I think you want to look at [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/persistence-160890.html), especially the annotation-based persistence for POJOs.

Comment: How densely is the historgram populated? Is *every* possible combination of indexes pointing to a `Point` object? If so, it could help to avoid the extra objects and just have parallel arrays for the values. It won't be as nice to work with, but you could safe a significant amount of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS is already making hard drive space into RAM for you and every process of course -- no magic needed. This will be more of a performance disaster than you think; it will be so slow as to effectively not work.

Are you looking for memory-mapped files?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

If this is really to be done in memory, I would bet that you could dramatically lower your memory usage with some optimization. For example, your `Point` object is mostly overhead and not data. Count up the bytes needed for the reference, then for the `Object` overhead, compared to two `ints`.

You could reduce the overhead to nothing with two big parallel `int` arrays for your x and y coordinates. Of course you'd have to encapsulate this for access in your code. But it could halve your memory usage for this data structure. Millions fewer objects also speeds up GC runs.

Instead of putting a `WritableRaster` in memory, consider writing out the image file in some simple image format directly, yourself. BMP can be very simple. Then perhaps using an external tool to efficiently convert it.

Try `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` to reduce object overhead too. Also try `-XX:NewRatio=20` or higher to make the JVM reserve almost all its heap for long-lived objects. This can actually let you use more heap.

Comment: I didn't show it in my example but the Point object also contains color data. I would love to chuck the Point class in lieu of something much smaller; however there are at least three (the largest) classes that would have to be rewritten almost entirely. Poor design choice at the beginning. If I re-write the program, I will address this issue. 

Do you know of a way to write directly to a JPEG? Getting rid of the raster would be a godsend. If not I'll write to BMP. The only reason for JPEG is that of the many I've tried, the best mass image resizer only accepts JPEG files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to configure your JVM memory parameters (Xmx) in order to make the operating system to allocate from it's swap memory. apparently the garbage collection mechanism needs to have random access to heap memory and if doesn't, the program will thrash for a long time and possibly lock up. please check the answer given already to my question (last paragraph):

[does large value for -Xmx postpone Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697433/does-large-value-for-xmx-postpone-garbage-collection)